# Resize diagonal lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, pixel, dimensions

I have a picture made of lots of diagonal line (45°) with a width of 1-2 pixels.

Now I have to resize this image and make it four times bigger than the original.

The problem is that now every pixel has become 4 times bigger too:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically set these lines border to 1 pixel?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Probably not. If these are just pixels, then Photoshop doesn't know it's a line.  All Photoshop sees is pixels. You may be able to use a hack, for example using vector shapes, and a posterize filter to remove antialiasing - but it's probably more trouble than it's worth, as it would mean recreating everything using vector shapes. [see example](https://imgur.com/NRBFRCn)

Comment: Thanks for the response... The image is only made of pixels, so remaking it from zero doesn't make sense. I'm gonna take a good pencil and do it by hand. Greetings

Comment: I've added this as an answer, just in case it's useful for anyone else. Yeah your probably right, it would be just as easy to redo it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably no way to automate this easily.  The problem is that if these are just pixels, Photoshop doesn't "know" it's a line.

You may be able to use this hack. However it's probably more trouble than it's worth to be honest.

1. Recreate your artwork as vector shapes, with strokes and/or fills.
2. Apply a Posterize adjustment above all layers to remove all anti-aliasing, set to a suitably low number of levels.
3. Then when you scale the image, the pixel count will increase, and so Photoshop will render the vector shapes with more pixels.

Example

[image]